# why pdf generate first row only?

Tags: php, html, pdf-generation

I generating pdf using mpdf class. the first row of the data is generated .

```
<?php
                    $host="localhost"; 
                    $db_user="root"; 
                    $db_password=""; 
                    $dbname="test"; 


                    $connect=mysql_connect($host,$db_user,$db_password) or die(mysql_error());
                    $select_db=mysql_select_db($dbname);
                    require_once('mpdf.php'); 
                    ob_start(); 
                    ?>
                    <META HTTP-EQUIV="Content-Type" CONTENT="text/html; charset=UTF-8">

                    <style type="text/css">
                    <!--
                    @page rotated { size: portrait; }
                    .style1 {
                      font-family: "Times New roman";
                      font-size: 18pt;
                      font-weight: bold;
                    }
                    .style2 {
                      font-family: "Times New roman";
                      font-size: 16pt;
                      font-weight: bold;
                    }
                    .style3 {
                      font-family: "Times New roman";
                      font-size: 16pt;

                    }
                    .style5 {cursor: hand; font-weight: normal; color: #000000;}
                    .style9 {font-family: Tahoma; font-size: 12px; }
                    .style11 {font-size: 12px}
                    .style13 {font-size: 9}
                    .style16 {font-size: 9; font-weight: bold; }
                    .style17 {font-size: 12px; font-weight: bold; }
                    -->
                    </style>
                    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
                    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
                    <html>
                    <head>
                    <META HTTP-EQUIV="Content-Type" CONTENT="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
                    </head>
                    <body>
                    <div class=Section2>
                    <table width="704" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                      <tr>
                      <td width="291" align="center"><span class="style2">Heading1</span></td>

                      </tr>
                      <tr>
                        <td height="27" align="center"><span class="style2">Heading2  </span></td>
                      </tr>

                    </table>
                    <table width="200" border="0" align="center">
                      <tbody>
                        <tr>
                          <td align="center">&nbsp;</td>
                        </tr>
                      </tbody>
                    </table>
                    <table bordercolor="#424242" width="1141" height="78" border="1"  align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="style3">
                      <tr align="center">
                        <td width="44" height="23" align="center" bgcolor="#D5D5D5"><strong>aaa</strong></td>
                        <td width="44" height="23" align="center" bgcolor="#D5D5D5"><strong>bbbb</strong></td>
                        <td width="178" align="center" bgcolor="#D5D5D5"><strong>bbbbb</strong></td>
                        <td width="123" align="center" bgcolor="#D5D5D5"><strong>vvvvvvvvv</strong></td>
                        <td width="123" align="center" bgcolor="#D5D5D5"><strong>vvvvvvvvv</strong></td>

                        </tr>

                        <?php
                    $objConnect = mysql_connect("localhost","root","") or die("Error Connect to Database");
                    $objDB = mysql_select_db("test");
                    //mysql_query("set NAMES'UTF8'");
                    $strSQL = "SELECT * FROM main_details";
                    $objQuery = mysql_query($strSQL);
                    $resultData = array();
                    while($data = mysql_fetch_array($objQuery)){
                       array_push($resultData,$data);
                    ?>
                      <tr>
                         <td align="right" class="style3"><?php echo $result['$i'];?></td>
                        <td align="right" class="style3"><?php echo $result['batch'];?></td>
                        <td align="right" class="style3"><?php echo $result['center']; ?>  
                        <td align="right" class="style3"><?php echo $result['code']; ?></td>
                         <td align="right" class="style3"><?php echo $result['created_at']; ?></td>

                        </tr>

                      <?php } ?>

                    </table>
                    <table width="200" border="0">
                      <tbody>
                        <tr>
                          <td>&nbsp;</td>
                        </tr>
                      </tbody>
                    </table>

                    </div>
                    </body>
                    </html>
                    <?Php
                    $html = ob_get_contents();
                    ob_end_clean();
                    $pdf = new mPDF('th', 'A4','0',''); 
                    $pdf->SetAutoFont();
                    $pdf->SetDisplayMode('fullpage');
                    $pdf->WriteHTML($html, 2);
                    $pdf->Output();
                    ?>
```

why my pdf generate first row only. i cannot find the error.How to get the pdf correctly

Answer (score 1):

First of all, I don't know why you use  this line `array_push($resultData,$data);`, since you are not using it anywhere of the code you provided.

Then, the second issue you have is you are using echo for array that is not exist, may be that's why you are only getting the first row, which is I believe the header.

so please change these lines:

```
<tr>
                         <td align="right" class="style3"><?php echo $result['$i'];?></td>
                        <td align="right" class="style3"><?php echo $result['batch'];?></td>
                        <td align="right" class="style3"><?php echo $result['center']; ?>  
                        <td align="right" class="style3"><?php echo $result['code']; ?></td>
                         <td align="right" class="style3"><?php echo $result['created_at']; ?></td>

                        </tr>
```

to

```
<tr>
                             <td align="right" class="style3"><?php echo $data['$i'];?></td>
                            <td align="right" class="style3"><?php echo $data['batch'];?></td>
                            <td align="right" class="style3"><?php echo $data['center']; ?> </td> 
                            <td align="right" class="style3"><?php echo $data['code']; ?></td>
                             <td align="right" class="style3"><?php echo $data['created_at']; ?></td>

                            </tr>
```

I guess you should be fine with that.
Update:
As for displaying the header on each page, here is one solution, it works by setting a counter and increment it each time, once it reaches 50 (or the maximum lines per page - which is for you to set) it will print the header again.
Here is the Code:

```
<?php $linesPerPageCount =0;
while($data = mysql_fetch_array($objQuery)){

                    ?>
                    <?php if($linesPerCount == 50){
                    $linesPerCount = 0;
                    ?>
                    <tr align="center">
                        <td width="44" height="23" align="center" bgcolor="#D5D5D5"><strong>aaa</strong></td>
                        <td width="44" height="23" align="center" bgcolor="#D5D5D5"><strong>bbbb</strong></td>
                        <td width="178" align="center" bgcolor="#D5D5D5"><strong>bbbbb</strong></td>
                        <td width="123" align="center" bgcolor="#D5D5D5"><strong>vvvvvvvvv</strong></td>
                        <td width="123" align="center" bgcolor="#D5D5D5"><strong>vvvvvvvvv</strong></td>

                        </tr>
                    <?php
                    }
                      <tr>
                         <td align="right" class="style3"><?php echo $result['$i'];?></td>
                        <td align="right" class="style3"><?php echo $result['batch'];?></td>
                        <td align="right" class="style3"><?php echo $result['center']; ?>  
                        <td align="right" class="style3"><?php echo $result['code']; ?></td>
                         <td align="right" class="style3"><?php echo $result['created_at']; ?></td>

                        </tr>

                      <?php $linesPerCount++; } ?>
```

Comment: Missing a closing `td` also.

Comment: working well but the table heading in first page only, how to set table heading in all pages